# WebDriver click on "Java window"

Tags: java, popup, click, webdriver

I'm saving files from the Application, and have this save window:

---

[image]

---

Here to press "OK" button I used next method:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

After this window Java Loading application to open it:[image]

And After this I have this window and previous code doesn't work here, I can't press Enter:[image]
Who know how to Click on "Run" on the last screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think again it will be a lot easier to use Sikuli for the job. You can do it with the simplest hello world example- http://doc.sikuli.org/tutorials/helloworld/helloworld-win.html